# AssertJ: Asserting that a an array of objects with fields (and values) contains (equals) another array of objects with fields (and values)

Tags: assertj

I am trying to figure out if I can write a terser program code than the one I came up with until now.

I start with sharing the code snippet and some explanation after the code snippet:

```
assertThat(produktUebersichtViews.size()).isEqualTo(4);

assertThat(produktUebersichtViews)
    .extracting("objectId", "typ", "title", "status", "bearbeiter", "bearbeiterName",
        "erledigungsFrist", "uebersichtTyp", "referencedProduktBasis")
    .containsAnyOf(
        tuple(ehbEinrichtung.getObjectId(), ehbEinrichtung.getProduktBasisTyp(),
            ehbEinrichtung.getName(), ehbEinrichtung.getZustand().name(),
            ehbEinrichtung.getBearbeiter(), ehbEinrichtung.getBearbeiterName(),
            ehbEinrichtung.getErledigungsFrist(), "PRODUKT_BASIS",
            ehbEinrichtung.getReferencedProduktBasis()
        )
    );

assertThat(produktUebersichtViews)
    .extracting("objectId", "typ", "title", "status", "bearbeiter", "bearbeiterName",
        "erledigungsFrist", "uebersichtTyp", "referencedProduktBasis")
    .containsAnyOf(
        tuple(ehbPerson.getObjectId(), ehbPerson.getProduktBasisTyp(), ehbPerson.getName(),
            ehbPerson.getZustand().name(), ehbPerson.getBearbeiter(),
            ehbPerson.getBearbeiterName(), ehbPerson.getErledigungsFrist(), "PRODUKT_BASIS",
            ehbPerson.getReferencedProduktBasis()
        )
    );

assertThat(produktUebersichtViews)
    .extracting("objectId", "typ", "title", "status", "bearbeiter", "bearbeiterName",
        "erledigungsFrist", "uebersichtTyp", "referencedProduktBasis")
    .containsAnyOf(
        tuple(ehbAbrechnung.getObjectId(), ehbAbrechnung.getProduktBasisTyp(),
            ehbAbrechnung.getName(), ehbAbrechnung.getZustand().name(),
            ehbAbrechnung.getBearbeiter(), ehbAbrechnung.getBearbeiterName(),
            ehbAbrechnung.getErledigungsFrist(), "PRODUKT_BASIS",
            ehbAbrechnung.getReferencedProduktBasis()
        )
    );

assertThat(produktUebersichtViews)
    .extracting("objectId", "typ", "title", "status", "bearbeiter", "bearbeiterName",
        "erledigungsFrist", "uebersichtTyp")
    .containsAnyOf(
        tuple(pruefbericht.getObjectId(),
            pruefbericht.getProduktErgebnisTyp(), pruefbericht.getName(),
            pruefbericht.getZustand().name(), pruefbericht.getBearbeiter(),
            pruefbericht.getBearbeiterName(), pruefbericht.getErledigungsFrist(),
            "PRODUKT_ERGEBNIS"
        )
    );
```

The variable `produktUebersichtViews` is a `Set` of a type `ProduktUebersichtView`. This type contains the fields listed in the `extracting` part.
I wonder if there are better ways (I'm confident there are) to write these assertions more concisely.
The set contains four objects; three of them are the same object type, one is a different type but containing almost all fields.
Ideally I would like to have two `assertThat` statements; one for the first three cases and one for the last case.

I tried not to clutter too much code in the question. Please let me know if you would like to have more information; I will try to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the problem you could filter by "PRODUKT_BASIS for the first 3 cases and simply write one `contains` assertion, something like:

```
assertThat(produktUebersichtViews)
      .filteredOn(p -> p.getUebersichtType().equals("PRODUKT_BASIS"))
      .extracting("objectId", "typ", "title", "status", "bearbeiter", "bearbeiterName",
                  "erledigungsFrist", "uebersichtTyp", "referencedProduktBasis")
       // not writing the full tuple ... 
      .contains(tuple(ehbEinrichtung.getObjectId(), ...),
                tuple(ehbPerson.getObjectId(), ...),
                tuple(ehbAbrechnung.getObjectId(), ...));
```

Comment: Wonderful thought. Thanks for your time.